# Copying contents of stringstream C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm using this code to copy a stringstream into another one:

```
std::string a("Hi my name is Bob"), b, c, d;
std::stringstream as, bs;
as << a;
getline(as, b, ' ');
bs << as.rdbuf();
getline(bs, c, ' ');
getline(as, d, ' ');
std::cout << b << c << d;
```

I would expect (and it's what I'm looking for) this as an output:

```
Himymy
```

But instead I get:

```
Himy
```

How can I modify it to get the wanted result?

Comment: suggest to change wording, "copy contents of stringstream" (streams cannot be copied)

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it rn

Comment: do you actually want to work with the strings and the streams are just your solution? In that case `substr` would be easier

Comment: Why do you expect `Himymy`? `bs << as.rdbuf()` reads from `as`'s internal buffer, advancing its position, until eof is reached, thus there is nothing left for `getline(as, d, ' ')` to read from the same buffer.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you use `getline` to get space-delimited words? Why not the simple `>>` operator?

Comment: I made an example with the space, but in my case I also have other characters

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's just a solution to the problem. My task is to get a command from the user until a certain character is typed. Then I should verify its syntax and if it's good I should do some operations. So I get the whole command with a `getline(cin, command, ';')`, I check it, I create a stringstream `stringstream s(command)` and I start "parsing" it... I don't actually know if it's a good approach but It worked fine until now

Answer (score 4):

From [this output stream `operator<<` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) about the buffer overload of `operator<<`:

> **extracts** characters from the input sequence controlled by `sb` and inserts them into `*this`

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

It *extracts* character from the source buffer, which means that they are removed and that the source buffer will become empty. It doesn't copy the contents, it *moves* it.

To get the expected output you need to copy the string contents:

```
bs << as.str();
```

Comment: Ok, so should I work with strings instead, or there's a solution with strings?